# How to use the silhouettevisualizer of yellowbrick in affinity propagation?n?

Tags: python

I was trying to visualize the Silhouette Coefficient from a model based in affinity propagation and I received this error:

AttributeError: 'AffinityPropagation' object has no attribute 'shape'

I wait to visualize the Silhouette Coefficient in a model performed by affinity propagation.

The code tested:

```
segmentacao  = AffinityPropagation(preference=-1000, max_iter = 250)
segmentacao.fit(compact)
labels = segmentacao.predict(compact)

from yellowbrick.cluster import SilhouetteVisualizer
visualizer = SilhouetteVisualizer(segmentacao, colors='yellowbrick')

visualizer.fit(segmentacao)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()        # Finalize and render the figure
```

Comment: where is the rest of the code ?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)